# Which is more efficient for yielding to another thread in win32

Tags: multithreading, winapi, synchronization, sleep, win32-process

SwitchToThread and Sleep(0)?

SwitchToThread - Suspends the execution of the current thread until the time-out interval elapses.. Causes the calling thread to yield execution to another thread that is ready to run on the current processor. The operating system selects the next thread to be executed.

Sleep(0) - A value of zero causes the thread to relinquish the remainder of its time slice to any other thread that is ready to run. If there are no other threads ready to run, the function returns immediately, and the thread continues execution.

Comment: What are the performance constraints. Please define "efficient".

Comment: time, space, CPU utilization, effectiveness, behavior

Comment: Except as documented on Windows XP there really doesn't seem to be any difference between the two, other than there return value when the function doesn't cause a switch to another thread. However, if you're calling either these functions you're probably doing something wrong. If you want to be "efficient" you either shouldn't be polling or you shouldn't interrupt your polling with either of these calls, depending on what you're actually doing and what sort of "efficiency" you really need.